# How do I concatenate a letter on to the end of a string with a for-loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have this homework challenge and can not seem to figure it out. Very new to coding so please be gentle.

"Create a new function called loveTheH that takes in a string as an argument. In the function, create a for loop that runs 10 times, and each time concatenates an 'H' on the end of the string passed in. When the for loop is done running (but still inside the function), return the resulting string."

So far I have the following:

```
function loveTheH(string){ 
    for(i = 1; i < 10; i++){ 
        return string; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: What code do you have so far? Hopefully you attempted this before coming to StackOverflow for the answer ;)

Comment: Can you please present what you have worked on so far?

Comment: [Start here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)

Comment: Don't have much yet... I'm just haveing a brain fart on what to put next. function loveTheH(string){
  for(i=1;i<10;i++){
    return string;
  }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> function loveTheH(string) {
>     for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
>         return string;
>     }
> }
> ```

Actually you return the string in the first loop without adding something.

You could declare the counter variable `i` with a [`var` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) and add the letter to the actual string  with an [addition assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment).

The `for` loop needs to loop until smaller or equal of ten, because you need ten times to add an `'H'`.

At the end of the function return the value of `string` variable.

```js
function loveTheH(string) {
    var i;
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        string += 'H';
    }
    return string;
}

console.log(loveTheH('yo'));
```

Answer (score 0):

> This should solve your problem, I think.

```
    function loveTheH(val)
{
    for (step = 0; step < 10; step++) {
      val=val+"H";
     }
    return val;
}
```